# How to load virtual environment for Python on Windows 10 using PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

Following Tyler Butler's [post](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/), I was able to install `pip`, `python` and `virtualenv` to my PowerShell. However, I can only enter a virtual environment where I have created it. If I open a new session of Power Shell, `workon` can only show me the the first virtual environment I that have ever created.

---

The initial loading of the first virtual environment
[image: The initial loading of the first virtual environment]

---

Unable to load the existing virtual environment. After specifying `workon venv`, nothing gets loaded
[image: Unable to load the existing virtual environment]

---

Unable to create the virtual environment under the same name, thus some thing has been in place.
[image: No more venv as new virtual environment]

---

After creating several more virtual environment, the `workon` command can only get me back `venv` as existing virtual environment.
[image: Nothing else are found as virtual environment]

---

Seeking help with getting the virtual environment function working in PowerSheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original answer

Thanks to the suggestions from: http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2014/06/19/install-python-setuptools-pip-virtualenvwrapper-for-powershell-pyside-on-windows/

Including the following specification to the File `~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, where `~` stands for the root folder of the user.

```
Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
```

As of now, in the new sessions of the PowerShell, `workon` functions nicely.

---

### Better alternative in 2018: Unix on Windows

Comment from 2018-11-26: please follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and use the Windows Subsystem for Linux instead.

The "subsystem" can freely access everything that exists in the Windows OS (e.g. use `/mnt/c/users/your-username` to visit the home directory), and I have been writing to the same project folder using both WSL terminals and Gvim on Windows with no problem (concern here maybe the LF vs CRLF conversion).